# Definition of a ResourceFunction

Tags: functions, documentation, resourcefunction

There is a feature called `ResourceFunction` in Mathematica. For example you can color a string with rainbow style.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RainbowText/

Below is a screenshot of the site in the Chrome browser.

[image: screenshot from the RainbowText resource function website]

As you see, the definition is not immediately visible, although it is available after downloading the source notebook (marked in light green) and opening the .nb file.

Below is a screenshot of the Mathematica program after opening the RainbowText-1-0-0-definition.nb file.

[image: the RainbowText notebook, opened in Mathematica]

Q1) Why are so many steps required to see the definition?

Q2) Can I get the definition of a resource function without downloading a notebook? I mean, just knowing the function name `RainbowText`, can I get the definition of `RainbowText`?

Comment: Seems that Domen has answered Q2. As for Q1, I think that a comment should suffice: it does not seem to be so uncomfortable to get the source notebook if one wants to have it, but this is not the intended use case/scenario for the general user. Presenting such information as the intended use case/scenario would likely result in some errors by the user when copying over the code blocks. By wrapping the functions in a contained format like that of the `ResourceFunction` allows for access to information like the version number, while also cleanly integrating with the overarching system.

Comment: `ResourceFunction["RainbowText", "Properties"]` for more info

Comment: Thank you CA Trevilian and Syed!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ResourceFunction["RainbowText", "Definition"]`

[image: Get Definition.]

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could use `"ResourceFunctionDefinitionViewer"`, to open a new notebook showing the implementation:

```
ResourceFunction["ResourceFunctionDefinitionViewer"][ResourceFunction["RainbowText"]]
```

[image: definition]

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the resource as an object rather than a function in order to make meta-queries:

```
ResourceObject["RainbowText"]["Properties"]
```

> ```
> {"AllVersions", "AutoUpdate", "Categories", "ContributorInformation", 
>  "Definition", "DefinitionNotebook", "DefinitionNotebookObject", 
>  "Description", "Details", "Documentation", "DocumentationLink", 
>  "DocumentationNotebook", "DownloadedVersion", "ExampleNotebook", 
>  "ExampleNotebookObject", "Function", "FunctionLocation", "Keywords", 
>  "LatestUpdate", "Name", "Originator", "Properties", "RelatedSymbols", 
>  "ReleaseDate", "RepositoryLocation", "ResourceLocations", 
>  "ResourceObject", "ResourceType", "SeeAlso", "ShortName", 
>  "SourceMetadata", "Symbol", "SymbolName", "TestReport", "Usage", 
>  "UUID", "VerificationTests", "Version", "VersionInformation", 
>  "VersionsAvailable", "WolframLanguageVersionRequired"}
> ```

The definition notebook:

```
ResourceObject["RainbowText"]["DefinitionNotebook"];
```

[image]