# Definition of ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"]

Tags: functions, documentation, resourcefunction

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256787/definition-of-a-resourcefunction) we can see definition of `ResourceFunction["RainbowText"]`.

[image]

The definition is quite obvious on the image (explicit open source).

We can get the definition also by code:

```
ResourceFunction["RainbowText", "Definition"]
```

When doing the same with [`ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntegrateByParts/) we have this definition:

[image]

What kind of definition is it? I can not see any open source code of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the definitions by using `PrintDefinitions`:

```
ResourceFunction["IntegrateByParts"];
ResourceFunctionHelpers`IntegrateByParts // GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions
```

Comment: If we compare it with `RainbowText` why does it have to be so much obscured and cumbersome?

Comment: In particular I am interested in how to choose custom `u` and `v` substitutions in integration by parts of that function.

Comment: It looks like `IntegrateByParts` is quite a lot more complicated, which is presumably why it's hidden behind a paclet update.

Comment: It is impossible in that mess to find out where choosing of `u` and `v` takes place in the definition.

Comment: @azerbajdzan  click on `udvlist`to get more information!

Comment: Note that it "looks like a mess" because the definitions that you get with ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions``` are shown in the `InputForm`, not the way you would usually type them in (which is the way they are shown in the Definition section of the resource function). And note  that basically all system functions look approximately like this if you look into their definitions.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thanks. I wonder why anybody bothers to make such complex function of integration by parts without option to choose custom substitution which would add a single line to the whole code???

Comment: It’s in Wolfram|Alpha internal code, hence not easy to spelunk.